# Ruby on Rails Date Field Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, date

I'm working on this project for a class and one of the requirements is "Validation on the date field type".

For example, I did:

```
rails g scaffold Tasks id:primary_key description:string due:date
```

What would I add to the model so I can validate the date?

I've tried multiple different "solutions" and nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your model, you can define a custom method to handle your validations.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :check_due_date


  def check_due_date
    # You can now check the "due" field here. For example, if you only want to allow due
    # dates today and later:

    if due < Date.today
      errors.add(:due, "can only be today or later.")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @Chuck: I disagree. If you used a before_save, then `task.valid?` could return true even if it really wasn't. And the only hook that executes between `validate` and `before_save` is `after_validation`, so unless the date is being messed around with inside an `after_validation` method, I wouldn't be concerned.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the simple "validates timeliness" plugin: https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness/

Then use the following syntax:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_date :due
end
```

Unless plugins aren't allowed, in which case the other answer (creating your own validator) would be more suitable.